# savefig('filename.png') saves a blank image in the folder

Tags: matplotlib, savefig

```
fig, ax = plt.xticks(datechange_index,datechange)
datacursor(display='single')
plt.ylabel('Temp in Kelvin')
plt.figure(figsize=(200,20))
plt.savefig('temp_plot.png')
plt.show()
```

The block of code above is what I tried to save a plot in matplotlib.  However, it ends up generating a blank image. I've tried a few solutions commonly suggested (which is why I have `plt.savefig` now above `plt.show()`, to no avail.

Comment: `plt.figure(figsize=(200,20))` creates a blank figure, right before you `savefig`.

Comment: Side note: [`pyplot.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) returns locs and labels... `fig, ax = plt.xticks` is quite a red flag.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the comment. Regarding the red flag, are you pointing out how the names of `fig` and `ax` suggest something different from `locs` and `labels` ?  I guess I will change them to `locs` and `labels`?

Comment: Yes, `fig` and `ax` suggest a `Figure` and `Axes`, which is most certainly not what `xticks` returns. So more meaningful names would be a good idea, for you and anyone who reads your code later.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you so much. I definitely have misled myself!

Answer (score 0):

@BigBen has answered this question:

> `plt.figure(figsize=(200,20))` creates a blank figure, right before you `savefig`

which explains why the OP initially was showing a blank figure.

Also, @BigBen went on further to flag that the naming convention used in the variables for the `xticks` function was misleading.